# Is it possible to have multiple Conjugate Priors?

Tags: bayesian, proof-explanation

In Bayesian probability theory, can a probability distribution have more than one conjugate prior for the same model parameters?

I know that the Normal distribution has another Normal distribution **or** the Normal-Inverse-Gamma distribution has conjugate priors, depending on what the model parameters are.

If multiple priors exists, then kindly cite some. If multiple priors do not exist, what is the proof that it cannot exist?

Comment: Two thoughts. 
First, should we speak of multiple (and alternative) choices of a prior, or should we speak of the most general prior? That is, if multiple choices exist, their weighted and re-normalised sum is also a prior (isn't it?). I bet the equivalent question is formulated and answered in terms of invariant spaces of integral equations.

Comment: Second (closely related to the above), consider some sort of a "natural" prior (e.g., the maximum entropy). Take the uniform distribution in [0,1] as a prior for the $\mu\in(0,1)$ in binomial model. Sticking it into the Bayes's formula gives Beta distribution--the "natural" conjugate. If this functional form is sufficient to express our prior belief about the likely values or the estimated parameter, there is no practical need to depart from this "natural" prior. If other conjugates exist, they must generalise Beta distribution (in order to include the "natural" flat prior as a possibility).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a conjugate prior density $f(\theta)$, then $h(\theta)f(\theta)/\int h(\tilde{\theta})f(\tilde{\theta})\,d\tilde{\theta}$ is another conjugate prior for any positive $h$ that is integrable wrt $f$. One therefore typically speaks of *a* conjugate prior rather than *the* conjugate prior.

Comment: Please do not put meta commentary in the question post.  This is the kind of thing which, at best, belongs in the comments.  That said, it is unlikely that the people who voted are your answer are likely to see the question.

Answer (score 1):

Consider two different point masses, $\delta_a, \delta_b$, as priors on $\theta$ of some likelihood $p_\theta(x)$. No matter your observations, the posteriors will then be equal to the prior. Thus both singleton families, $\{\delta_a\}$ and $\{\delta_b\}$, are conjugate prior families. A simple example of non-uniqueness.

Answer (score -2):

I am not 100% sure I understand your question, but consider a parameter space $\Theta$ with prior probability $f(\theta)$ and a probability distribution $p(x|\theta)$ over a space $X$ indexed by this parameter. The conjugate prior is simply obtained by computing Bayes rule:

\begin{equation*}
p(\theta|x) = \dfrac{f(\theta) p(x|\theta)}{\int_{\theta' \in \Theta}{f(\theta') p(x'|\theta)}}
\end{equation*}

Therefore, if $\theta$ (the model parameter) is given, the posterior distribution $p(\theta|\cdot)$ is unique and given this formula. Or, in other words, if $p(\theta|x)$ and $q(\theta|x)$ are two conjugate priors for $p(x|\theta)$, it is obvious that $p(\theta|x)=q(\theta|x)$ for any $x$.